# How to install Anaconda in a conda env?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I already have Miniconda installed with several environments. I would like to install the full Anaconda, in its own environment. For some reason, I cannot find any documentation that explains how to go about doing this. Does anyone know? I would like to have a yaml file for the installation, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried following [the](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) official documentation? Also which OS are you on?

Comment: I cannot find any official documentation that covers this situation. If you have some, please link to it since I'd love to see it. I am on CentOS 6. The only documention I've found is how to install fresh Anaconda/Miniconda and how to setup & manage packages in them, NOT how to install the full Anaconda as an environment within Miniconda.

Comment: I don't personally have much experience with Conda. But, I think the best way to get this answer would be to ask on their [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/conda) mailing list.

Comment: As far as I know, anaconda is just a (meta-)package in conda, so you should be able to do: `conda create -n new_environment anaconda`

Comment: How would I set up a yaml file for this for Python 2.7? `anaconda` goes under packages I am assuming?